# How to make this program better for code reuse?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, redmine

I have a program which extract data from SQL which is used with Redmine. The program works for normal AR extractions, but now we want to make extraction to other types. So we would have AR extraction, ICN extraction...
How can I make this code more general? I thought about creating a new namespace called "TypeLinker" which would determine the type passed then would assign different template to them. Is this a good idea?

**MAIN CODE**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        if (args[0] == "ALL" || args[0] == "*" || args[0] == "all")
        {
            PrintARs();
            Console.Read();
        }
        else
        {
            CreateARDocument(args[0]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static void PrintARs()
{
}

public static void CreateARDocument(string arg)
{
}
```

Comment: what is `AR` or `ICN`?  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for your question

Comment: Side note: AFAIK TLA is !ok on SO :) Meaning three letter acronyms (like AR?) are not very useful on StackOverflow. If you think AR & ICN (whatever they are) are important to your question - spell it out, otherwise just not use it.

Comment: Sorry, 
AR means Anomally Report, they are sure acronymes to different templates later used in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about the Factory pattern..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9319/Creating-a-Class-Factory-with-C-and-NET

Can also be done with an abstract base class.

Best regards.